# DestroyWindow() non-existant windows

Tags: c++, winapi

What I am working on has sets of window controls. Controls are constantly being either destroyed, or created.

```
void ChangeControl() {

// remove all controls, existing, or not
hwnd = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_BTN_FOOA);
DestroyWindow(hwnd);  
hwnd = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_BTN_FOOB);
DestroyWindow(hwnd);  
hwnd = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_BTN_FOOC);

// add the control wanted
hwndButton = CreateWindow("BUTTON", "Start", WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_OWNERDRAW|BS_PUSHBUTTON, 
        left, top, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_BTN_FOOB, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
}
```

Test case:

```
DWORD errorResult;
testHwnd = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_BTN_START); 
if (testHwnd) { 
    DestroyWindow(hwnd); 
}
else { 
    errorResult = GetLastError(); 
}
```

I am wondering if this method is safe, or if I should be checking if a control exists before calling `DestroyWindow()`.

Comment: Can you rig up a test to pass DestroyWindow a junk handle and then read GetLastError? That might let you know how safe it is.

Answer (score 1):

If the control doesn't exist then `GetDlgItem` returns `NULL`. Passing `NULL` to `DestroyWindow` should be "save" in the sense that it won't crash - it will return `FALSE` and `GetLastError` will be returning an "Invalid Handle" error (or something like that) (can't find any docs for it but that's the behaviour I've seen in the past).

A remark to your code:

> ```
> hwnd = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_BTN_FOOA);
> DestroyWindow(hwnd);
> ```

The use of two different variables which only differ in the capitalization of a single letter is ugly and error prone and you should use a different name. One convention I tend to follow if I select objects which are to be destroyed is to call them `doomed`. So maybe something like this:

```
doomedHandle = GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_BTN_FOOA);
DestroyWindow(doomedHandle);
```

Comment: Alright, the main code is updated, and works. There is one questionable thing left, and that is: does GetLastError() reset when you call it?

Comment: @EvanCarslake: I'm pretty sure `GetLastError()` doesn't reset the error code. To my knowledge the error code is only change when `SetLastError()` is called.